# How to Query Parent Account that has case

Tags: case, query, account, map

Scenario : **If a Account or it’s Parent Account has case then don’t update Product(another object) details**. I have queried from case object to find is there any account present in case and loaded to a set. Now checking all the incoming Account(with case and without case) with the collected set of case account. See below code sample for better understanding.

**Batch Apex
:**

```
Set<Id> caseInvolvedset = new Set<Id>();

    List<Case> caseInvolvedAccounts = [select Account, Account.Name from Case where Account != null]; //queried only accounts not parent account
    For(i=0;i<caseInvolvedAccounts.size();i++){
          caseInvolvedset.add(caseInvolvedAccounts[i].Account);
    }
     // collecting all the accounts that are with and without case 
    //Now checking whether the case Involved account is present in an Incoming Account like below
    If(!caseInvolvedset.contains(Account.ID)){
          //doing remaining processes
          //updating product
    }
```

**Now I want to check Parent Account that has case or not. If an Account doesn’t have a case and Parent account has then I shouldn’t update the Product details**. How to check with parent account also?.

Thanks

Comment: First we would need some more information, is this on a Batch, a trigger an anonymous code execution?

Comment: @Alexander Aeons Torn - This code is in Batch Apex

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see your `caseInvolvedset` contains Ids of all Accounts that have Cases so you just need to add one more check for a parent Account.

```
If(!(caseInvolvedset.contains(Account.ID) || caseInvolvedset.contains(Account.ParentId))){
      //doing remaining processes
      //updating product
}
```

It is not very clear from your question what you are trying to achieve as you are saying that you don't need to update a Product if Account has a Case but according to your code you are updating Product when there is a Case for Account. Anyway you should get the idea.

Comment: I missed ! in condition. Thanks for your thoughts i'll check on this and let you know

Comment: Oh I see, updated my answer